# How to edit the colors of a connector in Autocad Electrical?

Tags: connector, cad

how do I change the colors of a connector in Autocad electrical?

I want to change the connector outline and pin labels to black, but I can't find the layer or properties to do so.  The reason I am changing the color is because when I export to PDF, the connector doesn't not show up.

Thanks.

[image: Autocad connector example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother changing the screen colors.  When you go to plot the drawing to a PDF, just either plot it as monochrome, or create a new color mapping table for plots and use that.

Comment: This sounds like a better solution than mine.  I'm gonna try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found out you can change the color of the layer WIRENO.  WIRENO will update immediately after change.  For the connector color, go to the Home tab and change the layer color under the Properties section.  Now when you place the new connector, the color will be changed.  This will not change the existing connectors, so you will have to replace them with new ones.